# Jquery count checkboxes and override css

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, background-color

I am using jQuery that I found in another post, to count checkboxes that are checked.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(updateCount);
    });
    updateCount();

    function updateCount () {
        var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $("#count").text(count);
        $("#statusCount").toggle(count > 0);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="statusCount" class="text-center mbm">
    <span id="count">0</span><br/>
    <span class="featurecounter">Plans Selected</span>
</div>
```

My question:

What would I need to do in jQuery to achieve the following:

1. Check if the current count is > 4
2. If 1 is true change `.statusCount {background-color:red}`

Basically if the user selects more than , the background turns red.

Comment: You shouldn't use size() http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Just a question -- do you know what does this current updateCount() do?

Comment: Noted.. Thanks A. Wolff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your function `updateCount`

```
if (count > 4) {
   $("#statusCount").css('background-color','red');
} else {
   $("#statusCount").css('background-color','');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CAs2s/1/

Comment: Thanks zzlalani!  This did the trick.  really quite simple.  I need to quit procrastinating and learn JS.

Comment: There is a problem though.. When I deselect checkboxes bringing the total back down to <= 4 the box stays red.  I would like it to go back to its original color if that's possible.

Comment: Ya I took none out and replaced it with the hex for the original color and that worked as well.  Thanks again zzlalani!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class `.statusCount` if the checked `count > 4`

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(updateCount);
updateCount();

function updateCount () {
  var count = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
  $("#count").text(count);
  $("#statusCount").toggle(count > 0);
  if (count > 4) {
     $("#statusCount").addClass('statusCount');
  }
};
```